Understanding the definition of the covariant derivative
I'm currently working my way through the book "Mathematical Methods for Physics - An Introduction to Group Theory, Topology and Geometry" and I think I have a very fundamental misunderstanding when it comes to the covariant derivative of tensors.
The book states
$$
f_{;\mu\nu}=\nabla_\nu\nabla_\mu f=\partial_\nu\partial_\mu f-\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^\lambda\partial_\lambda f
$$
for scalar functions $f$ over some smooth manifold with connection coefficients $\Gamma^\lambda$.
But, on the other hand, it is stated that (for generic vector fields $X$) $$
\nabla_X f=X[f]=X^\mu\partial_\mu f
$$
and therefore $\nabla_\mu f=\partial_\mu f$, which would be a scalar. Applying this twice, I would obtain
$$
\nabla_\nu\nabla_\mu=\partial_\nu\partial_\mu f,
$$
which clashes with the expression given in the book. So where and how do the connection coefficients come in?
I have to say, I'm already confused by the definition given for $\nabla_X f$. Shouldn't the covariant derivative be a map from $(n,m)$-tensor fields to $(n,m+1)$-tensor fields?

For the scalar field, the equation is the one you wrote. For any vector field, like the gradient in your case, you must apply the covariant derivative.

But $\nabla_\mu f$ is a scalar if f is scalar, right? But it seems to me that it is treatted as a 1-form when evaluating $\nabla_\nu\nabla_\mu f$

No, $\nabla_\mu f=\partial_\mu f$ is a vector and must be treated as such. Therefore, you have to write $\nabla_\mu\partial_\nu f$.

If it was a vector, shouldn't we have: $f_{;\mu\nu}=\nabla_\nu\nabla_\mu f=\partial_\nu\partial_\mu f+\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^\lambda\partial_\lambda f$?

In the case of a scalar field, the covariant derivative equals the partial derivative.
In the case of a tensor field of higher rank, there are further terms involving connection coefficients: for rank $n$ there are $n$ such terms.
Starting from scalar $f$, one can obtain the first rank (i.e. 4-vector) field
$$
A_a \equiv \nabla_a f = \partial_a f
$$
The covariant derivative of this 4-vector field is then
$$
\nabla_b A_a = \partial_b A_a - \Gamma^\lambda_{ba} A_\lambda
= \partial_b \partial_a f - \Gamma^\lambda_{ba} \partial_\lambda f
$$
In other words it is all consistent. In particular, $\nabla_a f$ is of first rank (as the index implies). And of course one would expect a gradient of a scalar field to be like a vector field.
Coming now to the question about $\nabla_X$, yes this is a bit more subtle but it is not too bad. To get some intuition, consider the concept of differentiation along a line in the more familiar territory of Euclidean space. In this case if you have a scalar field $f$ then its gradient $\partial_a f$ is a vector field (given here in terms of its covariant components; you can call it a one-form if you like). But, for any given path specified by some $X_a(u)$, where $u$ is a parameter along the path, one can also obtain
$$
\frac{df}{du} = \frac{d X^\mu}{du} \partial_\mu f .
$$
From the indices one would say this is a scalar not a vector. That is right: it is a single number at each point on the path. However when combined with the specification of the path $X_a(u)$ it can be used to construct a vector, at least for points along the path.

Thank you very much for your answer, it makes a lot of sense to me and cleared up my confusion!
I think the main source of my confusion was the distinction between vectors (or one-forms, for that matter) and their components.


The covariant derivative of a covector field $V_\mu$ is:

$$ V_{\mu;\nu} = V_{\mu,\nu} - \Gamma^\lambda{}_{\mu\nu} V_{\lambda} $$

The covariant derivative of a scalar field is just its partial derivative, but the result is a covector field:

$$ f_{;\mu} = f_{,\mu} $$
Put 1 & 2 together, i.e. put $V_\mu = f_{;\mu}$, and I believe your confusion will be resolved.

Also note that when $X^\mu$ is a vector, the difference between $\nabla_X f$ and $\nabla_\mu f$ is very similar to the difference you know from standard vector calculus between $\vec{X}\cdot\nabla f$ and $\nabla f$. i.e observe that the analogous operations are:

$$ \vec{X}\cdot\nabla f =\vec{X}\cdot\big[(\hat{x}\partial_x+\hat{y}\partial_y+\hat{z}\partial_z) f\big] \Longleftrightarrow \nabla_X f = X^\mu f_{,\mu} \tag{1}$$
$$ \nabla f = (\hat{x}\partial_x+\hat{y}\partial_y+\hat{z}\partial_z) f \Longleftrightarrow \nabla_\mu f = f_{,\mu}\tag{2}$$
Namely, in $(1)$, you're taking the gradient with respect to some coordinate basis (with basis vectors $\hat{e}_\mu$) and immediately dotting the result with a certain vector field $\vec{X}$ written in that basis. Hence the result is indeed a scalar field.
In $(2)$, you're just taking the gradient of a scalar function $f$ with respect to some coordinate basis, which results in a covector field. The relation between the two operations then becomes clear from the above.

Thank you for clarifying that $\partial_\mu f$ is a covector field. It's a pet peeve of mine that people say it's a vector.

@CharlesHudgins I think the following is not widely appreciated, but correct: the difference between contravariant and covariant is not in the tensor itself, but in the way its components transform. So $A_a$ is a set of covariant components and $A^a$ is a set of contravariant components but the first-rank tensor $\bf A$ simply is what it is. (This perspective only works in the case of a manifold supplied with a metric, but that is the only case one needs to consider in the context of relativity.)

@AndrewSteane OTOH as you know the first rank tensor, even in a coordinate free description is either a linear map $V \rightarrow R$ or $V^{*}\rightarrow R$, so one can argue covariance/contravariance is already manifest on that level. But the point about the natural isomorphism (musical) we have in the context of relativity is correct. On a related note, see an interesting Phys.SE post on covariance/contravariance of the gradient
